# ASM call to C++

Tags: c++, assembly, memory, x86, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to learn some reverse engineering, but I got stuck at this.

I've got this asm code:

```
mov ecx,[0x00E81DAC]
push [ebp-04]
add ecx,04
mov eax,[ecx]
call dword ptr [eax+08]
```

As far as I understand, it sets to the **ecx** the result of the address **0x00E81DAC**

then it passes an argument **ebp** - 0x4 (**ebp** in my case is an integer argument lets say ***27590***)

then it adds to **ecx** +4 (so the **result** of 0x00E81DAC + 0x4?)

then it gets the **result** of **ecx** and sets it to eax

then it calls the **eax**+0x8

This is what I came up, but its wrong

```
DWORD* (__thiscall* callFunc) (int) = (DWORD* (__thiscall*)(int argument))((0x00E81DAC + 0x4) - 0x8);
DWORD* retValue = callFunc(27590);
```

The function should return a DWORD*

What would be the proper way to call this?

Comment: This seems to be a virtual function call. `ecx` is the `this` pointer, `eax` the vtable and `eax+8` is probably the second virtual function. So it's simply something like  `((foo*)0x00E81DAC)->bar(27590)`

Comment: _"...What would be the proper way to call this?"_ Drop your code to call the function into one of the online compilers and look at the assembly generated.

Comment: Every time there's square brackets, it's reading (or writing, but nothing here does that) memory at the location given by the expression inside the brackets. Work through the operations again keeping that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but i still didn't manage to make it. What would be the proper way to call this function like the example i gave you?

Comment: Ideally, you'd have the class of the object to call it properly.